# Different cases of variable name after append

Tags: stata, stata-macros

I have appended multiple files into a single sSata dataset. It has now `335` variable names. Some variable names have casing issues like `almirah` and `ALMIRAH` storing the same information from different datasets.

I am replacing these variables like this one by one:

```
count if mi(almirah)
local first=r(N)

count if mi(ALMIRAH)
local sec=r(N)

if first<sec {
    replace almirah=ALMIRAH if mi(almirah)
}
else {

}
```

How do I program this for all variables which are the same variable in essence but have upper and lower case issues like this?

Comment: Please read [How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/). We cannot be of much help if we cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have `frog toad newt` and `FROG TOAD NEWT`. Let's decide that the variable with lower case name is definitive. So, a loop with some or all of this may be helpful.

```
foreach v in frog toad newt { 
    local V = upper("`v'") 
    generate `v'2 = cond(missing(`v'), `V', `v') 
    display  
}
```

I have created a new variable there because there may be other problems. If there are, overwriting your data may obscure what they are.

Note: In your code segment you need at least

```
 if `first' < `sec'
```

to make it legal, as references to `first` and `sec` will be interpreted as references to variables or scalars otherwise. But it's really not clear why the numbers of missing values are material at all. If I have 42 observations, then `append` 66 more, the result should be the same as the other way round.

Comment: The variables names are not just in upper case. They occur in lower, upper any combination.  For example
schoolname SchoolName  
latitude Latitude  
almirah ALMIRAH

Comment: So, you need more complicated code in which you pair off the names yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help though.
The code above is a good start. Will further work on it.
Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I guess a good choice for you is lowering all variable names before appending data. If this guess is correct, below code might give you a hint.

```
clear
save output, emptyok replace

foreach file in file1 file2 file3 file4 {
    use `file', clear
    ren *, lower
    append using output
    save output, replace
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation this is how I resolved it.

```
quietly ds
local dbvars = "`r(varlist)'"

foreach v in `dbvars' { 
local V = lower("`v'") 

// test if var exists
capture confirm variable `V'_synced 
if !_rc {
  di in red "`V'_synced  exists"
  replace `V'_synced  = cond(missing(`v'), `V', `v')  if missing(`V'_synced )
     }
  else {
     di in red "`V'_synced  does not exist"
  gen `V'_synced  = cond(missing(`v'), `V', `v') 
      }

}

// keep combined variables 
keep *_synced
```

Comment: Your first three lines could just be `foreach v of var * {`.

Comment: This code is dangerous insofar as e.g. `frog` is the result of `lower()` on many possible variable names, namely `FROG FROg FRog Frog fROG fROg fRog` and so on. So, it's looking for one-to-one correspondences when Stata's rules permit many-to-one correspondences, at least for variable names two or more characters long.

Comment: thanks for the code suggestion, although how would the many-to-one correspondence be implemented?

Comment: It's a consequence of your code, not a goal usually desirable in itself.